# Numerically sorting a variables contents

Tags: python, api, loops, sorting, int

What am I doing incorrectly here. I am returning numbers, but would like them to be returned in a lowest to highest order.

```
def bus():
    busurl = ('https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/9/Arrivals?stopPointId=IDHERE&app_id= % secret &app_key= % key')
    bus = requests.get(busurl)
    busarrival = bus.json()
    count = 0

    for i in busarrival:
        if count <= 2:
            status = (i['timeToStation'])
            result = (status / 60)
            print 'Next bus in {} mins'.format(result)
            count += 1
```

Comment: Fix your indentations. Where are you returning any values?

Comment: Sorry, I'm printing at the end, but what is printed is not in lowest to highest. How would I achieve this? I've tried employing status.sort, to no avail.

Comment: Use `sorted(busarrival)` it should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with a special `key` function to sort by the arrival times:

```
for i in sorted(busarrival, key=lambda i: i['timeToStation']):
    if count <= 2:
        status = (i['timeToStation'])
        ...
```

Or sort the list in-place before the loop:

```
busarrival.sort(key=lambda i: i['timeToStation'])
for i in busarrival:
    ...
```

Of course, this requires each of the entries to have to `'timeToStation'` field, and the field must be a number, and not a string. If it is a string, convert to number first, e.g. `key=lambda i: int(i['timeToStation'])`

Comment: Thank you for this and the explanation. I really appreciate it!